# Is there a good English translation of "Foundations of Geopolitics" by Aleksandr Dugin?

Tags: russian-language, translation, aleksandr-dugin, foundations-of-geopolitics

This book is fairly geopolitically significant, because it describes a lot of the recent events in the world as driven by Russia and Russian disinformation campaigns.

I'm looking for an English copy of this book in order to read it myself, but as of yet, I've been entirely unable to find a reliable one. There is [one on Amazon](https://smile.amazon.com/Foundations-Geopolitics-Geopolitical-English-Translation/dp/1521994269/), but it doesn't seem like it's particularly reliable, and doesn't even list a translator. The text is also extremely poor quality, and is broken in many places.

Does a reliably translated copy of this text exist anywhere?

Comment: [In regards to the inevitable topicality & quality discussion...](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/211/80)

Comment: Yeah, this is *not* a recommendation question despite starting with "Is there a ... [book]?"

Comment: I think it's on-topic as long as it's not phrased or interpreted as a request for lists of things (because you're asking for something specific).

Answer (score 2):

A 2018 [thesis](https://digitalcommons.du.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2516&context=etd)<sup>[1]</sup> on the book has this to say on the subject of pre-existing translations:

> Despite the importance of Foundations of Geopolitics to Russian strategic thought there has not been a translated edition published in English.

and since this is a fancy university thesis I'd hope they did their due diligence looking for a good translation. To supplement the thesis an appendix is included, which has English translations (good ones, I assume) of important sections of the text. Not a complete translation, but hopefully a high-quality partial translation nevertheless. The sentences at a quick glance make grammatical sense - more than can be said of the Amazon version!

I have not been able to find a complete, non-machine-translated English version. Neither has [Politics SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/25183), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/geopolitics/comments/7k4fel/are_there_any_reliable_english_translations_for/), or [this random forum](https://www.tigerdroppings.com/rant/politics/english-translation-of-the-foundations-of-geopolitics/71126913/).

<sup>[1]</sup> <sub>Fellows, Grant Scott, "The Foundations of Aleksandr Dugin's Geopolitics: Montage Fascism and Eurasianism as Blowback" (2018). *Electronic Theses and Dissertations*. 1516. https://digitalcommons.du.edu/etd/1516</sub>